# fetching images from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am building a small online shop where I have a parent table called 'products' and a child table called 'images'.

I have followed best practice and set up a foreign key constraint with the field `product_id` establishing a link between both tables.

**products**

```
product_id (PK parent table)
product_title
product_category_id
product-price
product_quantity
product_description
long_description
product_image
```

**images**

```
image_id (PK for child table)
product_id (foreign key)
product_image_two
```

NB: Each product will have 2 images, thus I want to retrieve a product based on its `product_id` and get the associated images from each table.

ie. the query pulls `product_image` from 'products' and `product_image_two` from 'images'

I have trawled through a multitude of posts on here about `JOIN` and tried to refactor other folks code so far without success.

**My Current Statement**

```
<?php

$query = query("SELECT p.* , i.* FROM products p,images i WHERE p.product_id=i.product_id"); 
confirm($query);  

while ($row = fetch_array($query)): 


?>
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? could you explain more detail about`without success.`

Comment: What actually is your issue? Are you getting an error, unexpected results?

Comment: Yes to clarify when I run my query, it seems to pull only product_image and not the product_image_two

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a `LEFT JOIN`. Using a `LEFT JOIN`, you can select everything in the product table but only rows from the images table if their corresponding key is present in the products table. So for example, your query could look like:

```
SELECT p.* , i.* 
FROM products p,
LEFT JOIN images i ON
  p.product_id = i.product_id
```

This will return every row in the products table, and a value of null for each column in the images table if no second image exists. Here is a simplified demo of what this does: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f1af7/2)

Comment: appreciate the steering Barry, will give this a go, essentially all im trying to do is pull from table 2 as well a table 1 based on the id

Comment: ive got an escape_string method. escape_string($_GET['id']) . " "); How would the complete query look based on this and my initial query above, thanks

Comment: Sorry @wengtee, I'm not familiar with PHP so I won't be much use on that front. I assumed the code you posted in the question was working and your issue was a SQL problem,

Answer (score 0):

Try with inner join: according to your explanation it should work

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.product_image, i.product_image_two FROM products p
inner join images i on 
p.product_id=i.product_id
```

Comment: modified it - a comma was not there

Comment: won't run, product_image_two does not reside in the products table

Comment: product_image_two is in image table , not is product table and in my code that is also from image table